How to setup NAT gateway with Centos 7 for Private server can access internet
I have the following system diagram:
Internet --> NAT gateway server (server 01) --> App server (server 02).
NAT gateway server can access the internet.
Server 01 and server 02 can ping each other.
Both servers are running Centos 7.9.
I want server 02 in the private subnet to access the internet through NAT gateway server 01.
The problem I have here is that server-02 cannot access the internet.
Can you help me with the reason and configuration solution for this case?
Server 01: IP: 192.168.100.100/24, GW: 192.168.100.254
Server 02: IP: 192.168.110.101/24, GW: 192.168.110.254
[centos@nat-gateway-server-01 ~]$ ip route
default via 192.168.100.254 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.100 metric 100
[centos@nat-gateway-server-01 ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: eth0
sources:
services: dhcpv6-client dns http https ssh
ports:
protocols:
masquerade: yes
forward-ports:
source-ports:
icmp-blocks:
rich rules:
rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.110.0/24" accept

[centos@nat-gateway-server-01 ~]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
[centos@nat-gateway-server-01 ~]$ ping 192.168.110.101
PING 192.168.110.101 (192.168.110.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.110.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.158 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.110.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.123 ms
--- 192.168.110.101 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.056/0.101/0.158/0.042 ms
[centos@nat-gateway-server-01 ~]$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=11.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=110 time=11.5 ms
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.584/11.596/11.608/0.012 ms
[centos@app-server-02 ~]$ ip route
default via 192.168.110.254 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
192.16.110.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.110.101 metric 100
[centos@app-server-02 ~]$ ping 192.168.100.100
PING 192.168.100.100 (192.168.100.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.100.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.158 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.100.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.123 ms
--- 192.168.100.100 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.056/0.101/0.158/0.042 ms
[centos@app-server-02 ~]$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
[centos@app-server-02 ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: eth0
sources: 192.168.100.100
services: dhcpv6-client dns http https ssh
ports:
protocols:
masquerade: yes
forward-ports:
source-ports:
icmp-blocks:
rich rules:
rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.100.0/24" accept

[centos@app-server-02 ~]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled


ens18 connected to the ISP Router and getting IP from the DHCP.
ens19 connected to my LAN network with IP address 192.168.100.10, this is manually configured.



For nat server:


Enable nat module:
sudo modprobe iptable_nat
Permanent network forwarding:
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
Post routing and forwarding for NAT Router:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens19 -j ACCEPT



For client server:


Print current route:


[root@server2 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref
Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens18
192.168.100.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens18


Delete the default route:
route del -net default

Verify the default route has been deleted:



[root@server2 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref
Use Iface
192.168.100.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens18


Add a new default gateway for the interface, The gateway IP should be the IP of Server 1:

route add default gw 192.168.100.10 dev ens18

Verify:


[root@server2 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref
Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.10  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens18
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens18

Now try to connect to the internet.

Configure DNS forwarder to access any web URL:


Configure the interface with DNS, Edit the interface configuration file or use nmcli command to add the DNS:

ls -lthr /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens18
DOMAIN=your-domain.local

Verify:


root@server2 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
Generated by NetworkManager
search your-domain.local
nameserver 192.168.0.21
nameserver 192.168.0.1

Change the value of commands correspondingly.
